AffineTransform scale not producing correct dimensions?
So i think the width of both of my images after scaling them with this AffineTransform method should be 1515 pixels. first one original width is 1516 and second one 1513. i load output pictures into a image editor and crop away the black to check the width of the content and its 1514, not 1515. and it does this often. in another case the width was supposed to be 1515 but when i checked it it was 1513.
what is going on??
btw the bufferedimage canvas is deliberately big at 2000x2000 so yoy can see where scaled content actually is
the error looks like it grows a little bit each time if the code is looped 100 times. also making the average variables doubles and not floats looks like it improves accuracy a little bit, maybe 1 pixel error average and not 1-2
the console output is this:
average width is: 1514.5  
original width 1 is: 1513  
original width 2 is: 1516  
scale-factor 1 is: 1.0009914077990747  
scale-factor 2 is: 0.9990105540897097  
WITHOUT rounding to nearest integer, new width of content1 should be: 1514.5  
WITHOUT rounding to nearest integer,new width of content2 should be: 1514.5  
when rounded to nearest integer, new width of content1 should be: 1515  
when rounded to nearest integer,new width of content2 should be: 1515

and then heres the code
File f1 = new File("...");
File f2 = new File("...");
BufferedImage b1 = ImageIO.read(f1);
BufferedImage b2 = ImageIO.read(f2);
double average_width = (b1.getWidth()+b2.getWidth())/((double) 2);
double scale1 = average_width/b1.getWidth();
double scale2 = average_width/b2.getWidth();

      System.out.println("average width is: "+average_width);
      System.out.println("original width 1 is: "+b1.getWidth());
      System.out.println("original width 2 is: "+b2.getWidth());
      System.out.println("scale-factor 1 is: "+scale1);
      System.out.println("scale-factor 2 is: "+scale2);
      System.out.println("WITHOUT rounding to nearest integer, new width of content1 should be: "+(scale1 * b1.getWidth()));
      System.out.println("WITHOUT rounding to nearest integer,new width of content2 should be: "+(scale2 * b2.getWidth()));
      System.out.println("when rounded to nearest integer, new width of content1 should be: "+(Math.round(scale1 * b1.getWidth())));
      System.out.println("when rounded to nearest integer,new width of content2 should be: "+(Math.round(scale2 * b2.getWidth())));

BufferedImage bo1 = new BufferedImage(2000, 2000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
BufferedImage bo2 = new BufferedImage(2000, 2000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(scale1, scale1);
AffineTransformOp atop = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
bo1 = atop.filter(b1, bo1);
File fo1 = new File("...");
ImageIO.write(bo1, "png", fo1);



Please [edit] your question to include the results you get, when you have an average width which doesn't have a fraction part.

@Progman so i ran a test when first image was 1515 wide and second was 1513 wide, so 1514.0 average. and no problems there. content of both output images was 1514 like expect.

Okay, then what do you expect when your "target" contains a width with half a pixel, as in 1514.5? So it has to be 1514 (rounding down) or 1515 (rounding up), but which one should it be and why? Keep in mind that you cannot expect "exact" results with floating operations, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

You can try rounding average_width before using it in calculations.

@dan1st i did that and it actually made error much bigger

@Progman but the target always has whole number of pixels, the width of original pictures. average with fraction value only important to see what scaling factor will be. i expect filter method to multiply original image width by some factor f, like 1.00345, and then round to nearest integer, which should be same as what output of console is...

@yellowHoggerz Can you show the results of running with something like double average_width = Math.round((b1.getWidth()+b2.getWidth())/((double) 2)); (which is what I suggested before).

@dan1st but i think that is same as doong (double) average_width = (b1.getWidth()+b2.getWidth())/((double) 2)); average_width = Math.round(average_width); and i said i tried that

When are you adding the average_width = Math.round(average_width);? If I don't see where/how you are using it (before your comment, I didn't know how you were doing it at all), I cannot assume it being correct. For example, if you do the rounding after the computation of scale1/scale2, it would be effectively useless.

@i am not rounding the average. the average is calced like the code says. i rounded average when you suggested and didnt work like i said earioer. i said yday that your idea of how to round average is no different to way i aolready tried to round avrrage. i expect affine method to treat calcs like my output on console does, but it does not

For what it's worth: I'm pretty sure AffineTransformOp uses Math.ceil(..) rather than Math.round(..) in its calculations (ie. to contain even 0.1 pixel, you need one pixel). I don't fully understand the code or its intentions (or the mention of loops etc). But of course, bugs happens in the JDK too...
